# Using PostCSS Lost grid with SASS throws a weird message

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sass, postcss

I am trying to use Lost grid with SASS in my gulp workflow. I installed gulp-postcss, gulp-sass and lost grid from npm and setup all things perfectly. Everything works well, but it shows the below message every time I start the gulp server:

```
Node#moveTo was deprecated. Use Container#append.
```

Everything works properly, but what does this mean? Is this an error message?

Comment: It's a deprecation message, probably on one of the modules you were using.

Answer (score 0):

It may caused by `cssnano@3.10.0`

No related issues on the github page yet.

This is my postcss chain on `package.json`

```
"browserslist": [
  "> 1%",
  "last 2 FirefoxAndroid versions"
],
"postcss": {
  "plugins": {
    "postcss-import": {},
    "autoprefixer": {},
    "cssnano": {
      "zindex": false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to `cssnano@v4.0.0-rc.2` solved the problem for me.

`yarn add cssnano@v4.0.0-rc.2`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your `angular/cli` to version `1.7.0` or greater, preferably `6.0.0` (which is at the time of this post on "beta")